# Detecting Gaussians in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, object-detection, gaussian

I have a greyscale image, represented by a histogram below (x and y axes are pixels, z axis is pixel intensity). 
Each cluster of bars represents an object, with the local maxima fairly approximating the centroid of the object. My goal is to find the Full Width Half Max of each object – so I'm roughly approximating each object as a Gaussian distribution.

How can I detect each cluster individually? I understand how to mathematically calculate the FWHM, but I'm not sure how to detect each cluster based on its (roughly) Gaussian features. (e.g., in the example below I would want to detect 6 clusters. One can see a small cluster in the middle but its amplitude is so small that I am okay with missing it).

I appreciate any advice - and efficiency is not a major issue, so I can implement relatively expensive solutions.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

To find the centers of each of these groupings you could use a type of [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), or similar linear optimization algorithm.

It will find its way to the maxima of a grouping. The issue after that is you wont know if you are at a local maxima (which in your scenario is likely). After your current search has bottomed out at the highest point, and you have calculated the FWHM for that area, you could set all the nodes your A* has traversed to 0, (or mark each node as visited so as to not be visited again), and start the A* algorithm again, until all nodes have been seen, and all groupings found.

Comment: I like this answer, and if I have time soon I'll try it out. Unfortunately I don't have enough background to implement this strategy quickly enough! Great idea though

Comment: A* might be a bit of overkill, something more naive will probably converge fast enough unless your data is very large/complicated. Good luck.

Comment: If you like this answer you can click the green check mark to choose it as the selected answer.